# How to ignore Error in an include aspx "var is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, include

Picked up a vb.net project (not my thing) so am a bit lost.

I have this error when rebuilding the solution:

"var" is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

This is in a "included" aspx file, the var is declared in the file that includes it...

If i declare the var to trick the compiler then i have

Local variable "var" is already declared in the current block

I am stuck, there must be a simple solution cause this seems to bit a pretty standard thing to do but can't find it

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a bit more code to the question please, like the whole or most of the function that you get this error?

Comment: Is it a <!--#include ? (this isn't really standard anymore) I did a test a it works fine. Maybe we can see a sample? Or try it on a smaller scale.

Comment: Just create a file named test_main.aspx with: 
<% Dim test_var As String = "test" %>
<!--#include file="test_include.aspx"-->
and a test_include.aspx with
<%test_var = "teste" %>

Comment: @the_lotus It is, what is the new way ? (this is indeed an old project)